# Fail to set static ip via registry key - windows ce 5.0

Tags: windows, windows-ce, regedit

I found my ip setting on
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Comm\PCCARD\PHOTON1\PARMS\TCPIP via windows ce remote registry editor.
After i change the ip address but it keep retrieve back the previous ip that i set on the pda. Anyway to fix this issue?
*I did succeed to change my ie home page via the registry editor.

sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

The obvious solution is to change the static IP address through the applet in the Control Panel.

Assuming you are looking for a programmatic solution, after modifying the registry key you can call `RegFlushKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);` to persist the change, and then reboot the device.

If you want the change to take effect immediately, i.e. avoid the reboot, you will need to rebind the adapter after setting up the new address. Here's an example (error handling omitted for clarity):

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile(L"NDS0:", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

// Assuming adapter is called PHOTON1.
// Append extra NUL, IOCTL_NDIS_REBIND_ADAPTER expects a MULTI_SZ.
WCHAR adapter[] = "PHOTON1\0";

DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_NDIS_REBIND_ADAPTER, adapter, sizeof(adapter), NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

CloseHandle(h);
```

Again, if you want the change to persist after a reboot, call `RegFlushKey` after updating the registry.

Comment: [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
 public static extern int RegFlushKey(IntPtr hKey);
const UInt32 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000003;
RegistryKey rKey;
 rKey.SetValue("IPAddress", IPAddress_,RegistryValueKind.MultiString);
                rKey.Close();
                IntPtr hkeylocalmachine = new IntPtr(unchecked((int)HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE));
                RegFlushKey(hkeylocalmachine);

Comment: Can you help me to check on this code? because after i set the registry key, there is still the same issue happend and there is no any exception message.

Comment: Sorry, when you say "the same issue happened", do you mean that the IP address never changes to what you set it to? Have you tried rebooting the device after calling `RegFlushKey`? (reboot is required if you don't rebind). Does `RegFlushKey` succeed (check the return value)?

Comment: RegFlushKey is succeed, the Ip address is changed and i can view it on remote registry editor. But after i reboot the device, i go check on the remote registry editor and the ip address is change back to the previous ip.

Comment: Are you sure the registry key is correct? Normally, the IP address is stored under `HKLM\Comm\<Adapter name>\Parms\TcpIp`. For instance, do you see anything under `HKLM\Comm\PHOTON1\Parms\TcpIp`? Also does the modified IE home page information survive a reboot?

Comment: If you can modify the IP address in the Control Panel, and the new IP address is used after a reboot, then the issue is almost certainly something to do with the registry key/path.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an hive registry (data are persisted into files) you can change the IP address once and then you will always see that address.

If you have a RAM based registry data are lost after a reboot (it seems your case) and then you need to write a startup program that at every boot set the device IP to the one you need.